# How to make couple of different lists using c#?

Tags: c#, list, testing

Got a quite huge problem. My task is to split the input text into sentences,then to split sentences into words. Here comes the code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TextAnalysis
{
static class SentencesParserTask
{
    public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
    {
        var sentencesList = new List<List<string>>();                    
        var splittedText = text.Split('.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '(', ')');

        List<string>[] mas = new List<string>[splittedText.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splittedText.Length; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = new List<string>();
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < splittedText.Length; j++)
        {
            mas[j]= GetWordsOutOfTheSentence(splittedText);
            bool isEmpty = !(mas[j]).Any();
            if(!isEmpty)
            sentencesList.Add(mas[j]);

        }
        return sentencesList;
    }

    private static List<string> GetWordsOutOfTheSentence(string[] splittedText)
    {
        var wordList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var sentence in splittedText)
        {
            var wordsArray = sentence.Split('^', '#', '$', '-', '+', '1', '=', ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r',',');
            for (int i = 0; i < wordsArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (wordsArray[i] != string.Empty)
                {
                    var fineWord = wordsArray[i];
                    wordList.Add(fineWord.ToLower());
                }
            }
        }

        return wordList;
    }

}
}
```

The main problem is on test 1)

> Failed : TextAnalysis.SentencesParser_Tests.CorrectlyParse_SentenceDelimiters
>     Input text: [a.b!c?d:e;f(g)h;i]
>   Sentence #0 is wrong
>     Expected is <System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>> with 1 elements, actual is <System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>> with 9 elements
>     Values differ at index [1]
>     Extra:    < "b", "c", "d"... >

My code just continue adding new words in list and then add that lists in main list.What should i do?

Comment: what you regard as a sentence and what is a word ?

Comment: also you can call .ToList after split ( from System.Linq)

Comment: you call `GetWordsOutOfTheSentence(splittedText)`, meaning that you use the whole text and use the result as if it was just a sentence. Did you mean to use `splittedText[ j ]`?

Comment: Could you also share the test method?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comments, you are passing the entire splittedText variable into GetWordsOutOfTheSentence and not just that sentence. This means you are passing the list of 9 sentences instead of one sentence. As suggested in the comments your code should pass the specific sentence instead.

```
public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
{
    var sentencesList = new List<List<string>>();                    
    var splittedText = text.Split('.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '(', ')');

    List<string>[] mas = new List<string>[splittedText.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splittedText.Length; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new List<string>();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < splittedText.Length; j++)
    {
        //Passes entire splittedText:
        mas[j]= GetWordsOutOfTheSentence(splittedText);

        //Passes just the relevant sentence
        mas[j]= GetWordsOutOfTheSentence(splittedText[j]);

        bool isEmpty = !(mas[j]).Any();
        if(!isEmpty)
        sentencesList.Add(mas[j]);

    }
    return sentencesList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i just used additional list to solve the problem. Thanks everybody,it was awesome!

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TextAnalysis
{
    static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
        {
            var sentencesList = new List<List<string>>();
            var splittedText = text.Split('.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '(', ')');

            foreach (var sentence in splittedText)
            {
                var wordsArray = sentence.Split('^', '#', '$', '-', '+', '1', '=', ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r', ',');
                var additionalMainList = new List<string>();
                var wordList = new List<string>();
                foreach (var word in wordsArray)
                {
                    if (word != string.Empty)
                    {
                        var fineWord = word;
                        wordList.Add(fineWord.ToLower());
                        additionalMainList.Add(fineWord.ToLower());
                    }
                }
                bool isEmpty = !(wordList).Any();
                if (!isEmpty)
                    sentencesList.Add(additionalMainList);
                wordList.Clear();
            }

            return sentencesList;
        }
    }

}
```